# Do not redirect specific user agents with Caddy

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

Considering this Caddy Caddyfile config

```
http://www.example.com {
  redir https://{host}{uri}
}
```

How can I make the redirect not happen for user agents that contain the words "foo", "bar", "b a z" or another arbitrary string?

I tried a named matcher with [header_regexp](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/matchers#header-regexp) but without negative lookahead I don't know how to write the regex. Maybe there is another way?

I tried a named matcher using an expression like `header_regexp('User-Agent', '(foo)') || header_regexp('User-Agent', '(bar)') || header_regexp('User-Agent', '(another one)')` but since I can [not](https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/issues/4112) negate the matcher with `not`, I cannot use it. Maybe one could write the expression itself in a negated way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
http://www.example.com {
  @notadumbclient `
    header_regexp('User-Agent', 'foo') == false
    && header_regexp('User-Agent', 'bar') == false
    && header_regexp('User-Agent', 'Something Else') == false
  `
  redir @notadumbclient https://{host}{uri} permanent
}
```